# Wordcloud Highcharts .NET

Tags: c#, .net, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am having an issue with the creation of a Wordcloud with Highcharts 7.1.2 with C# and .NET.

I can create the wordcloud just fine, but I can't set the weight of the words.

The piece of code below is what I currently have, as you can see I am trying to use the *Labelrank* as a mean to set the weight. I cannot find an example of the wordcloud in c#, but I found some in JS and they always set the weight of each word.

```
            List<Series> seriesList = new List<Series>();

            List<WordcloudSeriesData> newWordcloudSeriesDataList = new List<WordcloudSeriesData>();
            foreach (var data in datas)
            {
                newWordcloudSeriesDataList.Add(new WordcloudSeriesData
                {
                    Name = data.Name,
                    Labelrank = data.Rank
                });
            }

            seriesList.Add(new WordcloudSeries
            {
                Data = newWordcloudSeriesDataList,
                Rotation = new WordcloudSeriesRotation
                {
                    From = 0,
                    To = 0,
                    Orientations = 1
                }
            });
```

PS: I found a workaround.

When you create the json before sending it to the front, use

`chartinfo = chartinfo.Replace("labelrank", "weight");`

where chartinfo is the json.

Comment: I found this info https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.wordcloud.data , I will try to add to the graph the list of dict : {name : "foo", weight: double} as a string. Will keep you updated

Comment: I found a workaround: `chartinfo = chartinfo.Replace("labelrank", "weight");` where chartinfo is the wordcloud wrapped in a string before sending it to the front. I will not accept this as an answer.